# why tanh has different results in OpenCL and C++ function

Tags: c++, opencl

here is my OpenCL code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main(){
   std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
   cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
   cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[0];

   std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
   default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);

   cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
   std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";

   cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(default_platform)(), 0};
   cl::Context context = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, properties);

   cl::Program::Sources sources;

   std::string kernel_code=
        "   void __kernel simple_tanh(__global const float *A, __global float *B){       "
        "       B[get_global_id(0)]=tanh(A[get_global_id(0)]);                 "
        "   }                                                                               ";
   sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});

   cl::Program program(context,sources);
   if(program.build({default_device})!=CL_SUCCESS){
       std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
       exit(1);
   }

   cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float));
   cl::Buffer buffer_B(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float));

   float A[1]; A[0] = 0.0595172755420207977294921875000000000000f;

   cl::CommandQueue queue(context,default_device);

   queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float),A);
   queue.finish();

   cl::Kernel kernel=cl::Kernel(program,"simple_tanh");
   kernel.setArg(0,buffer_A);
   kernel.setArg(1,buffer_B);

    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(1),cl::NullRange);
    queue.finish();
    float B[1];
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_B,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float),B);

    printf("result: %.40f %.40f\n", tanh(A[0]), B[0]);
    return 0;
 }
```

after I compile with this cmd: g++ -std=c++0x  hello.cc -lOpenCL -o hello, and run it. I got different results of tanh function.

Using device: Tahiti
result: 0.0594470988394579374913817559900053311139 0.0594470985233783721923828125000000000000

the first is the cpu result, and the second is the OpenCL function. which one should I trust?

Comment: The two are equal with single-precision floats.  Why are you expecting 40-digit precision?

Comment: Geometric functions such as tan and cosine require intensive layers of Taylor series to accurately model. That said the majority of users don't require such an high level of fidelity that being off by a few hundren-millionths doesn't affect the program in any way which means the performance gains of simpler models wins-- in the majority of cases.


I assume you fall into that former camp than the latter. Is there a reason you need such high fidelity? Do you understand the principle of significant figures? It's unlikely the rest of your data is so precise.

Comment: thanks. using 40-digital is just to show the difference. And, the tanh function is used as my activation function in my machine learning code. the very small difference in each iteration will be accumulate to a relative big difference after 60000 iterations of the training samples, and then causes my neural network does not coverage fast as the one using cpu based c++ function.

Comment: Using float you are very lucky to get 10 digits that are equal.

Comment: should I use double?

Comment: @liqianghe: For machine learning, FP16 is seriously considered. FP32 is sufficient, FP64 is overkill. Note that using ReLu as the activation function agrees with `tanh` up to about 1 bit, yet both activation functions actually work in a neural network.

Answer (score 0):

When a kernel is unable to be vectorized by compiler(opencl), generated instructions could be scalar types. Then, x87 FPU computes 80 bit. SSE has precision more comparable to GPU, you need `float4` or `float8` in your kernel such that compiler can produce SSE/AVX which has closer precision to GPU.

Generally Intel's opencl compiler vectorizes better(for some old CPUs at least). Which implementation are you using? There can be differences even between GPUs but they all obey the rule of not crossing ULP limit. If you need more precision with GPU(and SSE/AVX), why not write you own series expansion function then? But it would make learning very slow but faster than a single FPU at least.

What is your CPU? What opencl platform are you using? Did you check generated codes for kernel with some profiler software or some kernel analyzer?

Above all, you shouldn't do this:

```
 cl::NDRange(1)
```

unless it's learning purpose. This will have %99 kernel launch overhead, %1 data copy overhead and close to zero compute latency. Maybe thats why it's using 80-bit FPU instead of SSE(on CPU). Try computing for multiple-of-8 ndrange values or use `float8` types in kernel to let compiler use vectorized instructions.

When global ndrange value is millions, it will have significant effect on learning time, not leraning iterations needed. If CPU can finish learning in 1 day with 1M iterations, maybe GPU can finish it in 1-hour even if it needs 10M iterations. Transcandental functions have high compute to data ratio so speed up ratio versus CPU is higher if you use more of them.

If you derive your own series expansion function to achieve more precision, it would still be much faster than single CPU core in this embarrassingly parallel kernel code.

If the neural network has only a few neurons, then maybe you can do N networks training at the same time and pick the best learner(if learning has any randomization)? So it picks even better results than CPU?

Comment: thanks. this is just an example program using one thread to show my problem. it does not related to vectorize and any performance issue. using the gpu result, my neural network learns slower than the one using the cpu result. this is why I care the result difference.